# Set margin for all child html elements using css3

Tags: css

I am trying to show buttons left and right and center but margin is not accepting. I do not know how to set margin only for all child html elements in CSS.

```css
  .wrapper * {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper>* {
  color: green;
  /* margin:12px*?
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="left">
    Button 1
  </button>

  <button class="center">
    Button 2
  </button>

  <button class="right">
    Button 3
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: As a note, if you are using Angular (as seen on the stackblitz example you provided in comments) you should add the corresponding tag to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `::ng-deep` to apply styles for child elements. Also change the 'left' and 'right' bottons position to 'relative' and use float values for those buttons to align left and right...

```
.wrapper::ng-deep *{
  margin:5px 8px 4px 2px;
  text-align:center;
}

.left, .right{
  position: relative;
}
.left{
  float: left;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
```

Check this now: https://stackblitz.com/edit/amexio-breadcrumb-demo-v7dtrb?file=src/app/app.component.css.

Hope this is what you expecting.

Comment: Not working..If i add more buttons: https://stackblitz.com/edit/amexio-breadcrumb-demo-vi25b8?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: i can see the margin in all buttons. 'left' and 'right' buttons are overlapping each other because the class contains the position is 'absolute'. If you want to align 'absolute' element then need to add margin (or left/right values) for each and every element individually

Comment: i have updated the styles now.. check: https://stackblitz.com/edit/amexio-breadcrumb-demo-v7dtrb?file=src/app/app.component.css

Comment: You are awesome..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `margin` on elements that are `position`ed, which is your case. For your way of displaying it, better we can do this way:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.left, .right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
.right {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}

button {
  background: #f90;
  border: 1px solid #960;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="left">Button 1</button>
  <button class="center">Button 2</button>
  <button class="right">Button 3</button>
</div>
```

And the above is responsive too! Check it out full screen.

Comment: Your concept is not working: Can you check this stackblitz-https://stackblitz.com/edit/amexio-breadcrumb-demo-dyncgr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcontent%2Fcontent.demo.component.css

Comment: Do not write css for button bcoz i am inserting html elements dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Use the ::ng-deep selector to select elements that are defined inside another component.

For your example ::ng-deep will allow you to define margins on your elements like so:

```
.wrapper{
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper ::ng-deep button {
  margin:0 20px;
}
```

Alternatively, you can float them evenly positioned using CSS-flexbox like so:

```
.wrapper{
  position:fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background-color:#ccc;
  height:60px;
  padding:10px;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%; 
  }
.wrapper ::ng-deep button{
  margin: 0 10px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  }
```

Comment: `::ng-deep` is an Angular selector, OP didn't mention Angular at all

Comment: Please clear the other css-styling you have in app.component.css and tell me if it is working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try setting the `wrapper` as a flex-container, and the justify its children to the `space-between`

If you want to see it on Stackblitz with your Angular code check here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/amexio-breadcrumb-demo-m1c8xp

**EDIT:** Added another example for centered buttons

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.wrapper * {
  color: green;
  /*flex: auto; Uncomment this if you want the buttons to span the full width of the container*/
}

.wrapper2 {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 10px;
  bottom: 100px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="">
    Button 1
  </button>

  <button class="">
    Button 2
  </button>

  <button class="">
    Button 3
  </button>
</div>

<div class="wrapper2">
  <button class="">
    Button 1
  </button>

  <button class="">
    Button 2
  </button>

  <button class="">
    Button 3
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I am trying like this but your concept is not working:https://stackblitz.com/edit/amexio-breadcrumb-demo-oraf57?file=src/app/app.component.css

Comment: @RojaS I updated my answer with another example for centered buttons. But let me ask you, what are you expecting to see? Many people have answered with multiple approaches but you don't seem to accept any of them; can you provide a better explanation about what are you expecting the layout to look like? Its hard with you just telling people "It doesn't work" and giving no hint on *how* it should work